# Match a part of a sentence and replace white space in that sentence

Tags: regex

I've been scratching my head over this one for a while now. Is it possible, with a single regex, to modify the following text:

```
123456    ABC - 14 days     there are eels in my hovercraft [blablabla]
```

to look like this:

```
there+are+eels+in+my+hovercraft
```

The main points are match whatever is after `days` minus the white space and whatever is before the last `[` minus the space before it. On top of that, the white spaces should be replaced by plus characters. I can do this with two regexes where one gets the desired text and the second one replaces the white spaces with plus characters. But I'm wondering if there is a clever trick (lookaround comes to mind), which could accomplish the same in one go.

Comment: `/days+([a-zA-Z ]*)/gi` this should give you `days there are eels in my hovercraft ` but using `\1` should only give the parts you want.  Then just replace `/\s/g` with `+` and you should have what you want.

Comment: @DavidStarkey I know how to do it with two regexes but I'm curious if it's possible with a single expression.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Should it work with any string other than `there are eels in my hovercraft` (in number of words)? I could write one for exactly that number of words, though it's a bit long...

Comment: @F.J Doesn't matter. Using http://www.regex101.com/ would be optimal.

Comment: @Jerry No, the text in place of `there are eels in my hovercraft` is variable in length.

Comment: Since regexes do only match something, it's not possible to modify strings with them. What platform are you using? It might have a functionality that can do it.

Comment: @Bergi Modifying in the sense of replace this with that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most straightforward and probably most efficient way to do this is to just use two regular expressions, however if the language you are using allows for using a function as the replacement then you can do this with one call.  For example with Javascript:

```
var s = '123456    ABC - 14 days     there are eels in my hovercraft [blablabla]'
var regex = /^.*days *| \[.*$|( )/g;
var result = s.replace(regex, function (match, p1) {
    return p1 ? '+' : '';
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/5fsEA/

Same approach using Python:

```
import re
s = '123456    ABC - 14 days     there are eels in my hovercraft [blablabla]'
result = re.sub(r'^.*days *| \[.*$|( )', lambda m: '+' if m.group(1) else '', s)
```

Comment: Nice, I like it. I guess this problem really does call for something higher than just a pure regex. Thanks for your tip!

Answer (score 0):

This could be done in a 2-step process:  (1) isolate the text you want using a regex match; (2) use the output of #1 in a regex substitution operation.

Here's an example in python:

```
import re
line = "123456    ABC - 14 days     there are eels in my hovercraft [blablabla]"
m = re.match("^.*days\s+(.+)\s+\[.*$", line)   # this gives us "there are eels in my hovercraft"
print re.sub('\s+', '+', m.group(1))  # this substitutes white spaces with '+'
```

Comment: OP did explicitly state that he wants a one-step process!